# Batched tensor creation inside torch.vmap

Tags: python, pytorch, vectorization, tensor

I want to create a tensor with `torch.zeros` based on the shape of an input to the function. Then I want to vectorize the function with `torch.vmap`.

Something like this:

```
poly_batched = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]])

def polycompanion(polynomial):
    deg = polynomial.shape[-1] - 2
    companion = torch.zeros((deg+1, deg+1))
    companion[1:,:-1] = torch.eye(deg)
    companion[:,-1] = -1. * polynomial[:-1] / polynomial[-1]
    return companion

polycompanion_vmap = torch.vmap(polycompanion)
print(polycompanion_vmap(poly_batched))
```

The problem is that the batched version will not work, because `companion` won’t be a `BatchedTensor`, unlike `polynomial`, which was the input.

There is a workaround:

```
poly_batched = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]])

def polycompanion(polynomial,companion):
    deg = companion.shape[-1] - 1
    companion[1:,:-1] = torch.eye(deg)
    companion[:,-1] = -1. * polynomial[:-1] / polynomial[-1]
    return companion

polycompanion_vmap = torch.vmap(polycompanion)

print(polycompanion_vmap(poly_batched, torch.zeros(poly_batched.shape[0],poly_batched.shape[-1]-1, poly_batched.shape[-1]-1)))
```

Output:

```
tensor([[[ 0.0000,  0.0000, -0.2500],
         [ 1.0000,  0.0000, -0.5000],
         [ 0.0000,  1.0000, -0.7500]],

        [[ 0.0000,  0.0000, -0.2500],
         [ 1.0000,  0.0000, -0.5000],
         [ 0.0000,  1.0000, -0.7500]]])
```

But this is ugly.

Is there a solution for this? Will this be supported in the future?

Note: If you use `torch.zeros_like` on an input to the function it works and creates `BatchedTensor` but this doesn’t help me here.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

We can `clone()` up to the dimensions we want to do the in-place operation, and then to `concatenate` the `tensor`s we have to match their `shape`s correctly using `None` to index the non-existent dimension:

```
poly_batched = torch.tensor([[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]])

def polycompanion(polynomial):
    deg = polynomial.shape[-1] - 2
    companion = torch.zeros((deg+1, deg+1))
    companion[1:,:-1] = torch.eye(deg)
    _companion = torch.concatenate([companion[:, :-1].clone(), (-1. * polynomial[:-1] / polynomial[-1])[:, None]], dim=1)
    return _companion

polycompanion_vmap = torch.vmap(polycompanion)
print(polycompanion_vmap(poly_batched))
```

Outputs:

```
tensor([[[ 0.0000,  0.0000, -0.2500],
         [ 1.0000,  0.0000, -0.5000],
         [ 0.0000,  1.0000, -0.7500]],

        [[ 0.0000,  0.0000, -0.2500],
         [ 1.0000,  0.0000, -0.5000],
         [ 0.0000,  1.0000, -0.7500]]])
```